# how to update this data in php.select any one checkbox home or office

Tags: php

[image]

```
<?php 
   $upd = "UPDATE savetable SET tmpname='".$filename."',address='".$res['address']."' where f_id ='".$fid."'";
   $upres=mysqli_query($con,$upd); 

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($upres)) { 
      echo '<pre>';print_r($row);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Jaydip , can please put your code here , or explain in well manner. so we get the more clear idea about your issue

Comment: we need much more code and clean format

Comment: if your question is not explained well than anybody can downvote your question.

Comment: while execute above this code what you get? any error? form is submited?

Comment: Okay this is good but not enough you have to also explain about your occuring error or warnings, so what will be the out put of ***echo '<pre>';print_r($row);***

Comment: From where did you use `tmpname` this is not in your table

Comment: from where you get your $fid ? , you are still not getting us please update your full code so we can help you to resolve your issue  ***HTML, JS, PHP***

Answer (score 0):

In your sql query 'tmpname' is not availabe in your table field. So, when fire Sql query it's gives php error..

Try to something like this....

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE savetable SET address='".$res['address']."' where f_id ='".$fid."'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: tmpname genereted danamically but problem is one selected checkbox home either office

Comment: why becomes f_id in same.i am getting like f_id='1',f_id='2'                 UPDATE savetable SET tmpname=''file_1480114800'',address='home' where f_id ='3'
UPDATE savetable SET tmpname=''file_1480114800'',address='home' where f_id ='3'
UPDATE savetable SET tmpname=''file_1480114800'',address='home' where f_id ='3'

Comment: Yes right!!... I think you can not use "tmpname" becuse this fields is not availabe in your table Then how can you use this filed for update? i don't understand your query.....

Comment: that is the tmpname is created on database u can see my code      $tmpfile = "file_".strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$savedata ="INSERT INTO savetable (tmpname,f_id,address,userid) values ('$tmpfile',$fid,$add,4)";